# How do I get the grids to look like this using Bootstrap 4 grids?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I can't figure out how to get the required result using Bootstrap 4 grid.
This is how the part of the site looks in desktop mode. 2, 3 and 6 are images while the rest are text.

[image: desktop]

This is how the same site should look like in mobile.

[image: mobile]

the HTML is:

```
<section class="col-12">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 order-2 order-sm-1">
                <divclass="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 order-1 order-sm-2">
                <img src=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                <img src=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 order-2 order-sm-1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 order-1 order-sm-2">
                <img src=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Here is a link to the project: https://rohithandique.github.io/Rare-Monk-Website/ and for 4,5,6 in the css, I put:

```
position: relative;
top: -25%;
```

to get the desired result. but it leaves a wide gap in the bottom. So how do I change my Bootstrap classes to get the desired result? I am a beginner.

EDIT: Tried all solutions and found out that using CSS grid gave more flexibility in this situation as the positioning of HTML elements were fixed and bootstrap 4 doesn't allow such mixing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)  a modern API that replaces flex and older CSS stuff.  You can achieve whatever layout you want.  Keep in mind that is bidimensional.
It's the best you can get.  Easy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Hey please try to use bootstrap fluid container in these way you will get the desired result you want for example.look up to the link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's grid are 
`display:flex`
`flex-direction:column`

you cant style them that way you will have to use custom css for it !!!!

its as simple as that.